# Simple jQuery Show / Hide

Tags: jquery

I have an input which is hidden which carrys a value based on that value I would like to show a menu item.

i.e. if value in field = 1 than show menu item 1
     else if value in field is not 1 then hide menu item 1

my jquery

```
$(function() {
    $("#sessionVal".val(==1){
        $("#adminMenu").show();
    });
    $("#sessionVal".val(!=1){
        $("#adminMenu").hide();
    });
});
```

Really simple I am sure for most can anyone help?

Comment: thought so can you point me right?

Comment: This isn't even compiling. Might be a good idea to write code that at least is syntactically valid before asking questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($('#sessionVal').val() == 1) {
    $('#adminMenu').show();
} else {
    $('#adminMenu').hide();
}
```

Should do the trick.

Note I am using == instead of === because I'm assuming the value attribute won't necessarily get returned as number

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if( $("#sessionVal").val() == 1) {
        $("#adminMenu").show();
    } else {
        $("#adminMenu").hide();
    };
});
```

Not sure when do you want it to run, in this example it will check the field once page is loaded, you can bind however click, focus or other events when it should be done..

Answer (score 1):

You got your syntax wrong

`if ( $("#sessionVal").val() == 1 )`

Answer (score 0):

Justin, instead of `.val(==1)`, try `.val()=='1'`, and the same for the other statement. I believe that would throw you an error, am I right?

Hope to have helped.